# Change a link programmatically in a masterpage with css and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

Does anybody know how to programatically change the ccs of a link in a masterpage in child pages?

For example I have a (navigation) list of links in my masterpage like so:

```
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="report.aspx" class="list-group-item active">Donuts&trade;</a>
        <a href="english_responses.aspx" class="list-group-item">English responses</a>
        <a href="irish_responses.aspx" class="list-group-item">Irish responses</a>
    </div>
```

In the navigation list I use the css class: list-group-item active to display the active link (which is coloured blue for active) and css class:list-group-item for normal links.

What I want is to change the active link for each child page programatically using c#.

Is there any way to do it with page_load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have few options:

- Add a `runat="server` to your anchor tag
- Use `HyperLink` control instead

**ASP:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID ="ReportHyperLink" 
               NavigateUrl ="report.aspx" 
               CssClass="list-group-item" runat="server" />
```

**code behind:**

```
ReportHyperLink.CssClass= "list-group-item active";
```

---

> cant seem to get the code behind to work if using in a masterpage 'child' page

You just need to find the control

**ASP:**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpHolder" runat="server">              
<asp:HyperLink ID ="ReportHyperLink" 
               NavigateUrl ="report.aspx" 
               CssClass="list-group-item" runat="server" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**code behind:**

```
ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("CpHolder");
HyperLink hp= (HyperLink)cp.FindControl("ReportHyperLink");
hp.CssClass= "list-group-item active";
```

---

Also a better approach , you can add a public property in the master page like this:

**master's code behind:**

```
public string ReportHyperLinkCssClass
{
    get {
        return this.ReportHyperLink.CssClass;
    }
    set {
        this.ReportHyperLink.CssClass= value;
    }
}
```

**Page Load Code**

```
var myMaster = this.Master as YourMasterType;
if(myMaster != null)
{
    myMaster.ReportHyperLinkCssClass = newCssClass;
}
```

Comment: Thats cool didnt think of that. but cant seem to get the code behind to work if using in a masterpage 'child' page thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of page load event you can do the same thing using **JQuery** also.

See the below code example of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var childerns = $('.list-group').children('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < childerns.length; i++) {
        if ($(childerns[i]).attr('href') == 'english_responses.aspx') {
            $(childerns[i]).attr('class', 'list-group-item active');
        }
    }
});
```

In above code I am changing the css from **list-group-item** to **list-group-item active** for anchor tag having **href="english_responses.aspx"**

Comment: this is the alternate way of doing the same thing with good performance using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain javascript or jquery will be much better and faster than using server side c# for something as simple as this but if you absolutely must like meda said, add a "runat='server'" to you anchor tag(better to use hyperlink control), alowing you to access the control from the server and change the Style attributes to your preferenece.

But i absolutely suggest using javascript.